# How to send data from from javascript to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make bus seat selection.
For this i want to send selected seat information , amount  to next modal.
when i am trying to do this it send object [object] 
this is my template code

```
<div class="row">
            <div class=" col-sm-6">

                <div class="jquery-script-center">

                    <div class="jquery-script-ads">
                        <script type="text/javascript"
                                src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                        </script>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1>Select your seat</h1>
                        <div id="seat-map">
                            <div class="front-indicator">Front</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="booking-details">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <h2>Booking Details</h2>
                                    <h3> Selected Seats (<span id="counter">0</span>):</h3>
                                    <ul data-id="id-40" id="selected-seats">5
                                    </ul>
                                    Total: <b><span id="total">0</span>&nbsp Rupees</b>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">

                                    <button type="button" class="open-myModal btn btn-info btn-lg continue" data-toggle="modal"
                                            data-target="#myModal">Book Seats
                                    </button>
                                     <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(document).on("click", ".open-myModal", function () {
                                         var myBookId = $('#counter');

                                         var wer = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(myBookId));
                                         alert(myBookId);


                                         $(".modal-body #seats").val( myBookId );
                                    });

                                    </script>

                                </div>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                                        <!-- Modal content-->
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
                                                </button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Fill Booking Details</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <form method="post" action="{% url 'initiate' %}">
                                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                                    <div class="row">

                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="package_name"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Package Name</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="package_name" name="package_name" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="name"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Your Name</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="name" name="name" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="mobile"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Mobile</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="mobile" name="mobile" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="email"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="email"
                                                                           id="email" name="email" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="address"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Address</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="address" name="address" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="city"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">City</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="city" name="city" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="package_name"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">State</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="state" name="state" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="pincode"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Pincode</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="pincode" name="pincode" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="amount"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Amount</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="amount" name="amount" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="seats"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Seats</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="seats" name="seats" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="travel_date"
                                                                       class="col-2 col-form-label">Travel Date</label>
                                                                <div class="col-10">
                                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                                           id="travel_date" name="travel_date" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Confirm</button>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="legend"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
                <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.seat-charts.js' %}"></script>

                <!-- <script src="jquery.seat-charts.js"></script>  -->
                <script>
                    var firstSeatLabel = 1;

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var $cart = $('#selected-seats'),
                            $counter = $('#counter'),
                            $total = $('#total'),
                            sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
                                map: [
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'ee_ee',
                                    'eeeee',
                                ],
                                seats: {

                                    e: {
                                        price: 650,
                                        classes: 'economy-class', //your custom CSS class
                                        category: 'Selected Seat'
                                    }

                                },
                                naming: {
                                    top: false,
                                    getLabel: function (character, row, column) {
                                        return firstSeatLabel++;
                                    },
                                },
                                legend: {
                                    node: $('#legend'),
                                    items: [

                                        ['e', 'available', 'Available Seat'],
                                        ['f', 'unavailable', 'Already Booked']
                                    ]
                                },
                                click: function () {
                                    if (this.status() == 'available') {
                                        //let's create a new <li> which we'll add to the cart items
                                        $('<li>' + this.data().category + ' Seat # ' + this.settings.label + ': <b>$' + this.data().price + '</b> <a href="#" class="cancel-cart-item">[cancel]</a></li>')
                                            .attr('id', 'cart-item-' + this.settings.id)
                                            .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                                            .appendTo($cart);

                                        /*
                                         * Lets update the counter and total
                                         *
                                         * .find function will not find the current seat, because it will change its stauts only after return
                                         * 'selected'. This is why we have to add 1 to the length and the current seat price to the total.
                                         */
                                        $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length + 1);
                                        $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc) + this.data().price);

                                        return 'selected';
                                    } else if (this.status() == 'selected') {
                                        //update the counter
                                        $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length - 1);
                                        //and total
                                        $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc) - this.data().price);

                                        //remove the item from our cart
                                        $('#cart-item-' + this.settings.id).remove();

                                        //seat has been vacated
                                        return 'available';
                                    } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') {
                                        //seat has been already booked
                                        return 'unavailable';
                                    } else {
                                        return this.style();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        //this will handle "[cancel]" link clicks
                        $('#selected-seats').on('click', '.cancel-cart-item', function () {
                            //let's just trigger Click event on the appropriate seat, so we don't have to repeat the logic here
                            sc.get($(this).parents('li:first').data('seatId')).click();
                        });

                        //let's pretend some seats have already been booked
                        sc.get(['7_1', '7_2']).status('unavailable');
                    });

                    function recalculateTotal(sc) {
                        var total = 0;

                        //basically find every selected seat and sum its price
                        sc.find('selected').each(function () {
                            total += this.data().price;
                        });

                        return total;
                    }

                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
                    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
                    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                    (function () {
                        var ga = document.createElement('script');
                        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
                        ga.async = true;
                        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                    })();

                </script>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 position">
                <img src="{% static 'img/image102.png' %}" height="450" alt="logo"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

line which have id = selected seat" is showing the selected seat.

i wrote this script which fired on click on **book seats** button

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(document).on("click", ".open-myModal", function () {
                                         var myBookId = $('#counter');

                                         var wer = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(myBookId));
                                         alert(myBookId);


                                         $(".modal-body #seats").val( myBookId );
                                    });

                                    </script>
```

and it is showing me this

```
[object Object]
```

please help me into this.

Thank in advance.

Comment: alert(myBookId.value()) ?

Comment: Jonas nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

You need to get element value instead of element

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-myModal", function () {
    var myBookId = $('#counter').val();

    var wer = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(myBookId));
    alert(myBookId);

    $(".modal-body #seats").val( myBookId );
});
```